# how to reuse (reference) variables from other rules block in gitlab ci?

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have am creating a gitlab ci and have rules as below:

```
include:
  - template: "Workflows/Branch-Pipelines.gitlab-ci.yml"

.rule_a:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $PRODUCTION_BRANCH
      variables:
        VAR1: "var1"

.rule_b:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $STAGING_BRANCH
      variables:
        VAR2: # I need to read from VAR1 in rule_a
```

How can I do something like `!reference [.rule_a, rules, variables, VAR2]`?

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#reference-tags

Answer (score -1):

You can't reference items in an arrary. But you could separate out your variables for `rule_a` into its own hidden key.

```yaml
.variables_1
  variables:
    VAR1: "var1"

.rule_a:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $PRODUCTION_BRANCH
      variables: !reference [.variables_1, variables]

.rule_b:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $STAGING_BRANCH
      variables:
        VAR2: !reference [.variables_1, variables, VAR1]
```

Comment: can I other variables to rule_a? suppose I need all the variables from variables_1 and I also need to add VAR3 to the variables of rule_a

Comment: It is smart but I have an error using this. I am asking a new question about it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70380844/how-reference-variables-in-job-rules-in-gitlab-ci

Comment: @AminBa yes. You'll see in `.rule_b` that the specific variable is referenced. In `.rule_a` the entire `variables` map is referenced. See also [rules reference examples](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#reuse-rules-in-different-jobs) in the docs.