# How reference variables in job rules in gitlab ci?

Tags: gitlab, yaml, gitlab-ci

I need to reuse variables in a gitlab ci job rules

```
include:
  - template: "Workflows/Branch-Pipelines.gitlab-ci.yml"

.staging_variables:
  variables:
    CONFIG_NAME: "staging"

.staging_rules:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $STAGING_BRANCH
      variables: !reference [.staging_variables, variables]

stages:
  - staging

staging:
  stage: staging
  rules:
    - !reference [.staging_rules, rules]
  script:
    - echo $CONFIG_NAME
  tags:
    - staging
```

However, I am seeing this `Syntax is incorrect` linting error:

```
jobs:staging:rules:rule:variables config should be a hash of key value pairs
```

I am using the example explained here:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#reference-tags

Please note that I can do this and it works:

```
include:
  - template: "Workflows/Branch-Pipelines.gitlab-ci.yml"

.staging_rules:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $STAGING_BRANCH
      variables:
          CONFIG_NAME: "staging"

stages:
  - staging

staging:
  stage: staging
  rules:
    - !reference [.staging_rules, rules]
  script:
    - echo $CONFIG_NAME
  tags:
    - staging
```

Comment: As denoted in the docs the rules be an array of key value pairs, but in your case it is an array that you try to merge with an array —> it would result in nested arrays. This is not possible.

Comment: @SuicideS3ason How should I make it work?

Comment: Sorry I misread the actual problem. I’m not sure if the rules section has support for reference tags already

Comment: @SuicideS3ason this is not true. You can see examples [directly in the GitLab docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#reuse-rules-in-different-jobs).

Comment: @sytech
Can you share your answer? It can be checked with gitlab ci linting tool

Answer (score 5):

Using `!reference`-keyword in referenced section with `!reference` is not possible at this moment.

[!reference documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#reference-tags):

> You can’t reuse a section that already includes a !reference tag. Only
> one level of nesting is supported.

For your needs you could use YAML-anchors. *(not tested)*

```
include:
  - template: "Workflows/Branch-Pipelines.gitlab-ci.yml"

.staging_variables: &staging_variables
  variables:
    CONFIG_NAME: "staging"

.staging_rules: &staging_rules
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $STAGING_BRANCH
      variables: *staging_variables

stages:
  - staging

staging:
  stage: staging
  rules:
    - *staging_rules
  script:
    - echo $CONFIG_NAME
  tags:
    - staging
```

**Update**

Since GitLab 14.8 it's possible to use [nested references](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#nest-reference-tags-in-script-before_script-and-after_script) up to ten levels deep in `script`, `before_script`, and `after_script` sections.

Comment: Nested references are still not allowed in anything but script-related properties (`script`, `before_script`, `after_script`), so you still need to use anchors at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

As stated in the comment above you produce a syntax error for the GitLab CI linting tool which tries to resolve the variables array from the referenced section.

Change your config to have the `!reference` tag like below:

```yaml
staging:
  stage: staging
  rules: !reference [.staging_rules, rules]
  script:
    - echo $CONFIG_NAME
  tags:
    - staging
```

*Note* that here the `- !reference` has changed to `rules: !reference […]`

This should fix your error

Comment: It is not working and this is not related to the problem I am referencing